# Why can't I add a (String -> JsBoolean) to a Map[String, JsValue]?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to add a `Map("foo" -> JsBoolean(false))` to my JsObject's .fields, and it always results in a `Map[String, Object]`. None of the usual type coercion techniques seem to obtain a `Map[String, JsValue]` for applying a new JsObject. What's the deal? Is a JsBoolean not a JsValue?

```
val bar = format.write(image)
val bazz = bar.asJsObject.fields
val wrong: Map[String, JsValue] = bazz + ("newBoolean" -> JsBoolean(true))
```

Comment: Can you provide a full (almost) compiling example of code, e.g. with import statements and what `format` and `image` are? I don't think `asJsObject` is a method that comes from Play JSON (or at least I wasn't able to find it). Also `fields` on a `JsObject` will yield a `Seq` of pairs, not a `Map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

badcook was on the right track; I was mixing up a couple of different JSON libraries.

Answer (score 0):

See if following example helps:

```
val bar = JsObject(List(("key", JsNumber(1))))
val bazz = bar.value
val wrong = bazz + ("newBoolean" -> JsBoolean(true))
```

This generates following:

```
wrong: scala.collection.Map[String,play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = Map(key -> 1, newBoolean -> true)
```